# Kubernetes kubectl set image: unknown command

Tags: kubernetes

I want to use the command `kubectl set image` to upgrade my deployment as detailed in the [kubernetes hello world walkthrough](http://kubernetes.io/docs/hellonode/), but whenever I do I get the following error:

```
Error: unknown command "set" for "kubectl"
```

My kubernetes version (obtained by running `kubectl version`) is the following:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"2", GitVersion:"v1.2.5", GitCommit:"25eb53b54e08877d3789455964b3e97bdd3f3bce", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"3", GitVersion:"v1.3.5", GitCommit:"b0deb2eb8f4037421077f77cb163dbb4c0a2a9f5", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`kubectl set` was added in 1.3, and your client is 1.2.5

Answer (score -1):

Furthermore, you can use this answer to get familiarize with the syntax of the set image command:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71849740/14486701

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable.