# How to set/change container image of the kubernetes deployment using a single command?

Tags: kubernetes

Or in simple words, what is syntax of the `kubectl set image`?

Note:
kubectl provides set image command but it often confuses developers. I hope this question helps =)

Answer (score 4):

We can use this format to easily remember how this command works:

```
kubectl set image deployment <deployment-name> <container-name>=<image-name>:<image-version>
```

For example:

```
kubectl set image deployment frontend simple-webapp=kodekloud/webapp-color:v1
```

Here in the above example, `frontend` is the deployment name, `simple-webapp` is the name of the container, `kodekloud/webapp-color` is the name of the image and finally, `v1` is the image version.

P.S.
If this helps, do upvote!

Wanna connect, feel free to share an invite at [Linkedin](https://www.linkedin.com/in/alihussainia)

Answer (score 0):

This command seems confusing because of below part in **bold**:

$kubectl set image deployment deployment-name **container-name=image-name:image-version**

Why are we setting image-name & version to container-name?

Because, we are updating the app/service currently in running state in a k8s cluster, started by a deployemnt. The app/service is an image in running state - the container.

Here, we are asking kubectl to change/update the app/service which is a container with name "container-name" with a new image called "image-name".